# How to determine active monitor of the current cursor location

Tags: delphi, multiple-monitors

I currently have an application which needs to have an awareness of which monitor the cursor is located when running in a multi-monitor configuration.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[GetCursorPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648390.aspx) and [MonitorFromPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534603.aspx).

Answer (score 6):

Don't forget Screen.MonitorFromPoint and Mouse.CursorPos - these WinAPI functions are encapsulated in the VCL.

Comment: Als remember that Mouse.CursorPos throws exceptions if there is no mouse pos. For example when the user session is disconnected (XP fast user switching or terminal server).