# how to "dock"/attach winforms forms

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

I'd like to attach two forms within the same app to each other like done by some of the music players such as winamp where the windows can be detached or attached together on one of the sides and after that moving one window movies the other one too !

There perhaps is a better term to describe this behavior

any patterns or code samples that do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found the solution
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/stickywindows.aspx
posting here for others

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589268/how-to-make-my-windows-form-app-snap-to-screen-edges)

This is for snapping to desktop edges, but you can probably adapt it to snap to another window...

Comment: hmm, snapping to desktop edges is better done using appbar api....e.g. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/csdoesshell3.aspx....I was looking for "attaching" patterns, positioning forms next to each other is relatively simple