# How do you attach two forms together in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to “dock”/attach winforms forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238503/how-to-dock-attach-winforms-forms)

I have two forms: MainForm and PanelForm.

I have set it up so that PanelForm is attached to MainForm by overriding the OnMove of the MainForm so that the PanelForm moves along with the MainForm. This is to simulate that PanelForm is a panel for the MainForm.

I can dock and undock and PanelForm from the MainForm, as well as collapse it.

The problem is when I minimize the the MainForm or it loses focus to some other application, and when I return to the MainForm, I have to manually Alt-Tab the PanelForm.

Is there a way to just attach the PanelForm to MainForm, without overriding OnMove or other things to simulate that it is attached?

Comment: Are you looking for a UserControl instead of a Form? Place the UserControl in the MainForm (typically inside a Panel to allow for easy setup) and it will follow along that way.

Comment: No. I want the panel outside of the MainForm, so that I can undock it.

Comment: @KenWhite none of those answer the question of how to make the PanelForm activate along with the MainForm. I ran the examples but they do not activate the two forms together. They just show a way to snap edges which I have already accomplished.

Comment: Did you try to set the Parent property of the PanelForm to MainForm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not have two "active" forms/windows at the same time.  However you can bring one or more windows to the foreground by activating your main window.  To do this use the `Form.Show(ownerForm)` override.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are experiencing the nature of forms. They are inherently independent. Maybe what you should do to ensure both forms are visible when you want them to be after they were previously hidden (minimized/another window in front of it) is to set focus to both of them successively

**EDIT**
Looks Like you already found an answer, but this could work too. Not as pretty as the accepted answer though. Just do it on both forms.

```
Timer timer;
bool resetting = false;
Form2 frm2;
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    frm2 = new Form2();
    frm2.Show();
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.Interval = 50;
    timer.Tick+=new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
}
private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer.Stop();
    resetting = false;
}

private void Form1_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!resetting)
    {
        timer.Start();
        frm2.Focus();
        this.Focus();
        resetting = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Setting focus to yourself in the event handler of your own `OnFocus` event results in infinite recursion.

Comment: Yeah I had run into this same problem. That was my reason to ask the question.