# Windows Forms Force everything half screen and put my form on top

Tags: c#, winforms, magnification-api

I know how to put my Form on top, but I'm striving for a more specific behavior:
I want my window to be on top of the screen, forcing all other windows half screen.
To illustrate what I want, open the Windows Magnifier tool and dock it to the top of the screen.

Does anyone know how to achieve this? Hints or nudges in the right direction most welcome :)

Thanks !!

Comment: This [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589268/how-to-make-my-windows-form-app-snap-to-screen-edges) will help you out on the docking on the desktop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an artice which covers it here - http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/csdoesshell3.aspx

The article contains a finished library which can be used in your own application.

Comment: EXACTLY what I need. Why didn't I see this article on my research. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I would not be surprised if to accomplish this you would need to call directly SetWindowPos or other native apis.