# How to make form, which can stick to screen borders

Tags: c#, winforms

My task is to make a sticky form, which can stick to top or bottom or left or right part of screen. So, if it sticks to left or right side of a screen - it should have maximal height and fixed width. If it sticks to top or bottom side - it should have a fixed height and maximized width (100% of a screen width). How can I make it in c# 4.0? Maybe there are some suitable off-the-shelf solution?

**UPDATE1**

Ok, it's a good link to stick a window. Big thx! Now I have a problem with setting width and height of the form while it is picked by mouse and moving.

```
namespace WordLearn
{
    public partial class FormWord : Form
    {
        private const int SnapDist = 70;
        private int currWidth = 0;
        private int currHeight = 0;

        public FormWord()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }



        private bool DoSnap(int pos, int edge)
        {
            int delta = pos - edge;
            return delta > 0 && delta <= SnapDist;
        }

        protected override void OnResizeEnd(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnResizeEnd(e);
            Boolean key = false;

            Screen scn = Screen.FromPoint(this.Location);
            if (DoSnap(this.Left, scn.WorkingArea.Left))
            {
                key = true;    
                this.Width = 200;
                this.Height = scn.WorkingArea.Height;
                this.Left = scn.WorkingArea.Left;
            }
            if (DoSnap(this.Top, scn.WorkingArea.Top))
            {
                key = true;
                this.Height = 200;
                this.Width = scn.WorkingArea.Width;
                this.Top = scn.WorkingArea.Top;
            }
            if (DoSnap(scn.WorkingArea.Right, this.Right))
            {
                key = true;
                this.Width = 200;
                this.Height = scn.WorkingArea.Height;
                this.Left = scn.WorkingArea.Right - this.Width;
            }
            if (DoSnap(scn.WorkingArea.Bottom, this.Bottom))
            {
                key = true;
                this.Height = 200;
                this.Width = scn.WorkingArea.Width;
                this.Top = scn.WorkingArea.Bottom - this.Height;
            }
            if (!key)
            {
                this.Width = currWidth;
                this.Height = currHeight;
            }

        }

        protected override void OnResizeBegin(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnResizeBegin(e);

            currWidth = this.Width;
            currHeight = this.Height;

            this.Width = 50;
            this.Height = 50;


        }
    }
}
```

I understand why it isn't resized to 50x50 px - because i dont fire ResizeEnd event after ResizeBegin... But how can I realize something like I described above?

**UPDATE2**

So, now I have the following code. This code stick form to a screens edges. But I want this form to resize (to size (200,200)) when user try to UNSTICK it.Because if he move big streched window it will sticked again by the next rule...

```
namespace WordLearn
{
    public partial class FormWord : Form
    {

        private const int stickDist = 100;

        private Screen scn = null;
        private int maxW = 0;
        private int maxH = 0;

        private int fixedW = 300;
        private int fixedH = 300;

        public FormWord()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void FormWord_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.scn = Screen.FromPoint(this.Location);
            maxW = scn.WorkingArea.Width;
            maxH = scn.WorkingArea.Height;
            Point p = new Point(0, 0);
            this.Size = new Size(fixedW, maxH);
            this.Location = p;
        }

        private void FormWord_Move(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (maxH != 0 && maxW != 0 && this.Location.X != 0 && this.Location.Y != 0 && this.Location.X != maxW-fixedW && this.Location.Y != maxH - fixedH)
            {
                label1.Text = this.Location.X.ToString() + ":" + this.Location.Y.ToString();
                if (this.Location.Y < stickDist)
                {
                    Point p = new Point(0, 0);
                    this.Size = new Size(maxW, fixedH);
                    this.Location = p;
                }
                else if ((this.Location.Y + this.Height) > (maxH - stickDist))
                {
                    Point p = new Point(0, (maxH - fixedH));
                    this.Size = new Size(maxW, fixedH);
                    this.Location = p;
                }else if (this.Location.X < stickDist)
                {
                    Point p = new Point(0, 0);
                    this.Size = new Size(fixedW, maxH);
                    this.Location = p;
                }
                else if ((this.Location.X + this.Width) > (maxW - stickDist))
                {
                    Point p = new Point((maxW - fixedW), 0);
                    this.Size = new Size(fixedW, maxH);
                    this.Location = p;
                }
            }     
        }

        private void FormWord_ResizeBegin(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Size = new Size(200,200);
            int x = 0;
            int y = 0;
            if (this.Location.Y == 0)
            {
                y = stickDist * 2;
            }
            else
            {
                y = this.Location.Y - stickDist * 2;
            }
            if (this.Location.X == 0)
            {
                x = stickDist * 2;
            }
            else
            {
                x = this.Location.X - stickDist * 2;
            }

            this.Location = new Point(x, y);
            Cursor.Position = new Point(x + 2, y + 2);

        }


    }
}
```

I try to do this resize in void FormWord_ResizeBegin, but it don't work. Could you help me have it work?

Comment: Do you want to affect the behavior of maximized windows?

Comment: if your window have maximized width then it will be stuck to both Right and Left edges of screen, are you sure what you want to do with your form?

Comment: I wrote that maximzed width and fixed height needed when it sticks to top or bottom edge.

Comment: SLaks, after launching program main window is sticked to right edge of a screen, it has a fixed width (200px) and maximal height. By some manipulations with this window I need the ability to stick this window to another sides of a screen by rules, which I described above in the question body. So, now I think a good idea is to minify window to small size (for example, 50px width and 50px height) while when user take and move a window by header. And if a user move this window very close to some screen side, form sticks.

Comment: windows already does this for you. This is a job for the window manager and not for individual apps on an be hoc basis.

Comment: Yes, windows makes it well for a left and right edges. But if i move window to a top side - it maximze the window, to a bottom side - do nothing. And it works only in windows 7, as I know.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make my Windows Form app snap to screen edges?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589268/how-to-make-my-windows-form-app-snap-to-screen-edges)

Answer (score 5):

You need to hook into the `ResizeBegin` and `ResizeEnd` events. These get fired when the form is moved as well as resized.

In these you can check the current position of the form and if it's within `X` pixels of the edge of the screen (where you determine the margin) call your code for resizing and positioning the form according to your rules.

You'll need to clarify the order the rules fire and put code in to ensure that the second rule doesn't fire as a result of the first resizing the window.

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) // On Form Load
{
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized)
    {
        maxW = this.Size.Width;
        maxH = this.Size.Height;
    }
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
}

private void Form1_Move(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (maxH != 0 && maxW != 0)
    {
        if (this.Location.Y < 100)
        {
            Point p = new Point(0, 0);
            this.Size = new Size(maxW, 700);
            this.Location = p;
        }
        else if (this.Location.Y > (maxH - 100))
        {
            Point p = new Point(0, (maxH - 700));
            this.Size = new Size(maxW, 700);
            this.Location = p;                
        }
    }     
}
```

hope thats what you needed!