# Drag a form to the screen borders to change its height/width

Tags: c#, .net, anchor, dock

in My LocationChanged event, i'd like to change the width/Height when i get closer with the screen borders.

i'm currently using the following code:

```
private void Form1_LocationChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        int BORDER_SIZE = 100;
        Rectangle border = new Rectangle(
        BORDER_SIZE,
        BORDER_SIZE,
        Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width - BORDER_SIZE,
        Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height - BORDER_SIZE);
    if(!border.Contains(Cursor.Position) ) 
    {
        this.Height = 400;
        this.Width = 50;
        radPanel1.Height = 400;
        radPanel1.Width = 50;
        this.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Right);
        radMenu1.Orientation = System.Windows.Forms.Orientation.Vertical;

    }
```

When i drag my form to the border in question (keeping my click pressed) it is working, i see my height and width changing but when i release my mouse, the width and height go back to their default values.
I don't understand why.
Moreover, the anchor does not work.

What am i missing please?
Thanks in advance
it drives me crazy

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make my Windows Form app snap to screen edges?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589268/how-to-make-my-windows-form-app-snap-to-screen-edges)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolved using the link posted