# WinForm : How to exclusively dock on a side of a screen

Tags: c#, winforms

After hours searching, I still haven't found any solution to my need.

By saying Exclusively docking I mean that it takes a part of screen (Left, Right, Top or Bottom) and the rest other programs cannot use that part. If you have Windows 8, it looks like the small part of 2 divisions function in Win8.

I have the solution for WPF, but now I need to do it basing on WinForm.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've done this before, unfortunately don't remember the specifics.  I do know that I need to use some Win API calls.

Comment: @Franva, I am curious as to how you did this in WPF, do you have any source reference material or demo code you could show. Cheers in advance

Comment: @recursive could you spare time to find it please?

Comment: @Jastill, I'd like to share the code with you if I could, but it's a commercial project so I cannot really do that, sorry

Comment: @Franva I'll see if I can find it tomorrow.

Comment: @Franva, you can't share a generic code snippet? working for the Military?? (it also seems like an oxymorn to ask someone else to find their code snippets, when you are denying someone else your own, jsut my 2 cents)

Comment: @Franva: lol, my code is from a commercial product too.

Comment: @Jastill Hi, don't be an angry bird. I am a graduate and I don't know too much about the privacy law so in order to avoid to get into trouble(breach of my company rules) I chose to not share(the author of that code is not me anyway), so that's my reason. If you dislike my answer, please just walk away and no more word game please.

Comment: @Franva, All good, I'm a newbie as well. 1 tip from a grad to a grad, don't be afraid to ask your co workers or boss if you are allowed to share code. They will understand that if you give some help you will get some in return in the future. that's how places like stack work.

Comment: @Franva: sorry, I don't have access to that source anymore, but if my memory is correct, the answer that I gave is what I used.

Comment: @Jastill Hi Jastill, you can take a look the link shared by recursive, it's the code my boss uses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use this awesome solution over at code project (the author Corneliu is/was a MVP): http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6045/Sticky-Windows-How-to-make-your-top-level-forms-to

Otherwise there is a great implementation from Hans Passant here: [How to make my Windows Form app snap to screen edges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589268/how-to-make-my-windows-form-app-snap-to-screen-edges)

**Edit:**

If you want to restrict other programs from using the space then try Arik Poznanski's [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) `Application Desktop Toolbars` method:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3728/C-does-Shell-Part-3

Comment: Your links are useful, but do any of those dedicate screen space to the application, denying its usage to other ones? I think he's looking for a [Application Desktop Toolbar wrapper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144177(v=vs.85).aspx). I've tested [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3728/C-does-Shell-Part-3) demo and it seems to work, however it still allows other windows to overlap the "dedicated" region.

Comment: @Jeremy Thompson, thx a lot bro, it works like a charm!!! The only glitch is that sometimes some apps can still go under/over the side bar...any idea?

Answer (score 2):

I can check tomorrow, but I believe when I implemented this, I used this as a guide.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6741/AppBar-using-C