# Windows Form app that takes up the top area of a screen?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

I'm trying to create a windows form app that "owns" the top area of a screen. Think of it as just a rectangular form width = screen size and height = 20px or so. The app would always be on top and would be borderless (i.e. FormBorderStyle=none). The questionable part, for example, if a user maximizes a window like chrome or some other application, it should treat the bottom of this windows form app as the top of the screen. This way since the form app is always on top, it doesn't cover up any of the maximized application's window.

Any clues on how to do this.. can it be done with windows forms? The only questionable part is how to "own" a portion of the screen.

Let me know if clarification is needed. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: I found this similar question w/ some seemingly valid answers:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14116824/winform-how-to-exclusively-dock-on-a-side-of-a-screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you  need  is to set the `Screen.WorkingArea` which is readonly  you should use PInvoke to achieve this you can find your answer in  this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267206/how-can-i-resize-the-desktop-work-area-using-the-spi-setworkarea-flag)

To get the working area of the display you can  use [`Screen.WorkingArea`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.workingarea%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property

Comment: OK- this seems like an OK solution however it visually cuts off parts of windows that are outside of the working area. So if I maximize a window the bottom is cutoff. If the working area rect is (Top=30px,Left=0px,Right=Screen.Width,Bottom=Screen.Height - 30px) then the bottom 30px of a maximized window is cut off (i.e. the horizontal scrollbar in a browser is apparently now beneath the task manager)..

Comment: ok I played around with it and changed the Bottom property to [Rect.Bottom = Screen.Height - (Rect.Top * 2)] and it seems to look fine.