# Is there a way to use Appbar without having explorer.exe process running?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, appbar

I implemented an AppBar to replace the windows task bar.
The AppBar will function normally if explorer.exe is running.

When explorer.exe is not running, any maximized window will dock to my entire screen size.

The AppBar should function normally regardless if explorer.exe is not running. What am I missing here? I have attached the code I am using below.

[AppBar **with** explorer.exe running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xt7Ly.png)

[AppBar **without** explorer.exe running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJZOA.png)

Public Class Form1

```
Public Enum AppBarStates
    AutoHide = &H1
    AlwaysOnTop = &H2
End Enum

Public Sub SetTaskbarState([option] As AppBarStates)
    Dim msgData As New APPBARDATA()
    msgData.cbSize = CType(Marshal.SizeOf(msgData), Integer)
    msgData.hWnd = FindWindow("System_TrayWnd", Nothing)
    msgData.lParam = DirectCast([option], Int32)
    SHAppBarMessage(DirectCast(ABMsg.ABM_SETSTATE, Integer), msgData)
End Sub

Public Function GetTaskbarState() As AppBarStates
    Dim msgData As New APPBARDATA()
    msgData.cbSize = CType(Marshal.SizeOf(msgData), Integer)
    msgData.hWnd = FindWindow("System_TrayWnd", Nothing)
    Return CType(SHAppBarMessage(DirectCast(ABMsg.ABM_GETSTATE, Integer), msgData), AppBarStates)
End Function

Structure RECT
    Public left As Integer
    Public top As Integer
    Public right As Integer
    Public bottom As Integer
End Structure

Enum ABMsg
    ABM_NEW = 0
    ABM_REMOVE = 1
    ABM_QUERYPOS = 2
    ABM_SETPOS = 3
    ABM_GETSTATE = 4
    ABM_GETTASKBARPOS = 5
    ABM_ACTIVATE = 6
    ABM_GETAUTOHIDEBAR = 7
    ABM_SETAUTOHIDEBAR = 8
    ABM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED = 9
    ABM_SETSTATE = 10
End Enum

Enum ABNotify
    ABN_STATECHANGE = 0
    ABN_POSCHANGED
    ABN_FULLSCREENAPP
    ABN_WINDOWARRANGE
End Enum

Enum ABEdge
    ABE_LEFT = 0
    ABE_TOP
    ABE_RIGHT
    ABE_BOTTOM
End Enum

Private fBarRegistered As Boolean = False
Private uCallBack As Integer

Private Sub RegisterBar()
    Dim abd As New APPBARDATA()
    abd.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(abd)
    abd.hWnd = Me.Handle
    If Not fBarRegistered Then
        uCallBack = RegisterWindowMessage("AppBarMessage")
        abd.uCallbackMessage = uCallBack

        Dim ret As Integer = SHAppBarMessage(CInt(ABMsg.ABM_NEW), abd) 'ToDo: Unsigned Integers not supported
        fBarRegistered = True

        ABSetPos()

    Else
        SHAppBarMessage(CInt(ABMsg.ABM_REMOVE), abd)
        fBarRegistered = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ABSetPos()
    Dim abd As New APPBARDATA()
    abd.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(abd)
    abd.hWnd = Me.Handle
    abd.uEdge = CInt(ABEdge.ABE_BOTTOM)

    If abd.uEdge = CInt(ABEdge.ABE_LEFT) Or abd.uEdge = CInt(ABEdge.ABE_RIGHT) Then
        abd.rc.top = 0
        abd.rc.bottom = SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize.Height
        If abd.uEdge = CInt(ABEdge.ABE_LEFT) Then
            abd.rc.left = 0
            abd.rc.right = Size.Width
        Else
            abd.rc.right = SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize.Width
            abd.rc.left = abd.rc.right - Size.Width
        End If

    Else
        abd.rc.left = 0
        abd.rc.right = SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize.Width
        If abd.uEdge = CInt(ABEdge.ABE_TOP) Then
            abd.rc.top = 0
            abd.rc.bottom = Size.Height
        Else
            abd.rc.bottom = SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize.Height
            abd.rc.top = abd.rc.bottom - Size.Height
        End If
    End If

    ' Query the system for an approved size and position. 
    SHAppBarMessage(CInt(ABMsg.ABM_QUERYPOS), abd)

    ' Adjust the rectangle, depending on the edge to which the 
    ' appbar is anchored. 
    Select Case abd.uEdge
        Case CInt(ABEdge.ABE_LEFT)
            abd.rc.right = abd.rc.left + Size.Width
        Case CInt(ABEdge.ABE_RIGHT)
            abd.rc.left = abd.rc.right - Size.Width
        Case CInt(ABEdge.ABE_TOP)
            abd.rc.bottom = abd.rc.top + Size.Height
        Case CInt(ABEdge.ABE_BOTTOM)
            abd.rc.top = abd.rc.bottom - Size.Height
    End Select

    ' Pass the final bounding rectangle to the system. 
    SHAppBarMessage(CInt(ABMsg.ABM_SETPOS), abd)

    ' Move and size the appbar so that it conforms to the 
    ' bounding rectangle passed to the system. 
    MoveWindow(abd.hWnd, abd.rc.left, abd.rc.top, abd.rc.right - abd.rc.left, abd.rc.bottom - abd.rc.top, True)
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
    If m.Msg = uCallBack Then
        Select Case m.WParam.ToInt32()
            Case CInt(ABNotify.ABN_POSCHANGED)
                ABSetPos()
        End Select
    End If

    MyBase.WndProc(m)
End Sub

Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams() As CreateParams
    Get
        Dim cp As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
        cp.Style = cp.Style And Not &HC00000 ' WS_CAPTION
        cp.Style = cp.Style And Not &H800000 ' WS_BORDER
        cp.ExStyle = &H80 Or &H8 ' WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW | WS_EX_TOPMOST
        Return cp
    End Get
End Property

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    RegisterBar()

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    RegisterBar()
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    If GetTaskbarState() = 1 Then
        SetTaskbarState(AppBarStates.AlwaysOnTop)
    Else
        SetTaskbarState(AppBarStates.AutoHide)
    End If

End Sub
```

End Class

Public Class NativeMethods

```
Sub New()
End Sub

Structure APPBARDATA
    Friend cbSize As Integer
    Friend hWnd As IntPtr
    Friend uCallbackMessage As Integer
    Friend uEdge As Integer
    Friend rc As RECT
    Friend lParam As IntPtr
End Structure

Friend Declare Function SHAppBarMessage Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "SHAppBarMessage" (ByVal dwMessage As Integer, ByRef pData As APPBARDATA) As IntPtr
Friend Declare Function GetSystemMetrics Lib "User32.dll" Alias "GetSystemMetrics" (ByVal index As Integer) As Integer
Friend Declare Function MoveWindow Lib "User32.dll" Alias "MoveWindow" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer, ByVal cx As Integer, ByVal cy As Integer, ByVal repaint As Boolean) As Boolean
Friend Declare Auto Function RegisterWindowMessage Lib "User32.dll" (ByVal msg As String) As Integer

<DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)>
Friend Shared Function FindWindow(strClassName As String, strWindowName As String) As IntPtr
End Function
```

End Class

Comment: _"The AppBar should function normally regardless if explorer.exe is not running."_ does the documentation state that, or is it your opinion?

Comment: The documentation does not state that, that is what my desired result should be. It does not state that explorer.exe should be running as a requirement either.

Comment: Most shell32.dll functions communicate with, or are in some way related to explorer. May I ask why you would not run explorer while running your app??

Comment: @VisualVincent, my overall goal is to replace the shell and run the PC in a 'kiosk' mode but still have some basic functions. All that I am looking for is being able to dock the app to the bottom. If I am unable to use shell32.dll, I am open to alternatives.

Comment: If you're looking to create a kiosk mode application then killing explorer isn't enough. Using [**Secure Desktops**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682573(v=vs.85).aspx) is the way to go.

Comment: If you're looking to dock a window on the screen you might also be interested in this question (of course, modifications would be necessary): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14116824/winform-how-to-exclusively-dock-on-a-side-of-a-screen