# How do I snap a borderless Form to the edges of a screen?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

When I set the form's border style to none, I can no longer snap the window to the edges of the screen. How can I have both?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aero Snap requires a window with a border, no back-door.  You could emulate snapping with the code in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/591734/17034).

That's still a far cry from the interactive feedback the user gets from Aero Snap.  There is more than one way to get a borderless window, another way is by intercepting the [WM_NCCALCSIZE message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632634%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  A message that Windows sends to give an app the opportunity to override the client area size of a window.  That's *very* easy to do, set the FormBorderStyle property back to Sizable and paste this code into your Form class:

```
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
        const int WM_NCCALCSIZE = 0x83;
        if (m.Msg == WM_NCCALCSIZE && m.WParam.ToInt32() == 1) {
            m.Result = new IntPtr(0xF0);   // Align client area to all borders
            return;
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

Beware that you probably already have overridden this method to make the window sizable.  Just update it with this code.

Every hack like this produces yet another problem, the client area of your window will now be too large.  Larger by the size of the borders and the window caption.  Fixing this is tricky, Aero lies about border sizes and you have to ensure that auto-scaling for DPI still works correctly.  Set FormBorderStyle back to None and make the constructor of the Form look like this:

```
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        var designSize = this.ClientSize;
        this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.Sizable;
        this.Size = designSize;
    }
```

Keep in mind that even though the window now has the border style flag turned on, you still won't get a drop-shadow.  Hard to fix, CS_DROPSHADOW is as good as it gets.

Answer (score -1):

Just providing an alternative that I didn't managed to get it on stackoverflow.

Got this code from [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/570233/AeroplusSnappluseffectplusforplusformpluspluswithp).

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
   get
   {
      CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
      {
         cp.Style |= 0x20000 | 0x80000 | 0x40000; //WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_SYSMENU | WS_SIZEBOX;
      }
      return cp;
   }
```

}