# detect if Windows + ArrowKeys was pressed

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'm currently making a WindowsForms application with FormBorderStyle = none.
I'm near to finish my project but the only thing that bothers me is tht I can't "dock" my window using the windows + arrow key combinations. 
The problem is that combinations with the windows key cannot be read using an KeyEventHandler. 
If someone has an idea how to read these key combinations with some kind of Api or anything please help.
The Tag for vb.net and C# is used becase translation between them is easy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I snap a borderless Form to the edges of a screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30421288/how-do-i-snap-a-borderless-form-to-the-edges-of-a-screen)

Comment: @BartHofland Unfortunately that doesn't work. On my Windows 10 (20H2) using this code does not give me any aero snap functionality. It just removes the border of a sizable window after which it just acts like a window with formborderstyle of none