# Enable snap layout on custom maximize-restore button and apply shadow around borderless form

Tags: winforms, winapi, wndproc, dwm

I have a borderless form with a custom max-restore button, the max-restore button is a custom class with overriden WndProc that returns HTCAPTION when the message is NCHITTEST, that properly shows the snap layout when mouse is over.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHG5C.png)

However, if in the constructor of the form I put the DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea method, there is a nice shadow around the form but the snap layout does not appear anymore.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BchXo.png)

How can achieve to have both.

This is the form code:

```
    public partial class Form4 : Form
    {
        private MaxButton maxButton;
        public Form4()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            maxButton = new MaxButton();
            maxButton.Location = new Point(50, 50);
            maxButton.Size = new Size(50, 50);
            Controls.Add(maxButton);

            // Set the border thickness
            MARGINS margins = new MARGINS
            {
                Left = 1,
                Top = 1,
                Right = 1,
                Bottom = 1
            };

            // Apply Border
            DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(Handle, ref margins);
        }

        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            if (m.Msg == 0x0084)/*NCHITTEST*/
            {
                Point screenPoint = new Point();
                GetCursorPos(ref screenPoint);
                Point clientPoint = PointToClient(screenPoint);

                if (clientPoint.Y <= 10)
                {
                    if (clientPoint.X <= 10)
                        m.Result = (IntPtr)13/*HTTOPLEFT*/ ;
                    else if (clientPoint.X < (Size.Width - 10))
                        m.Result = (IntPtr)12/*HTTOP*/ ;
                    else
                        m.Result = (IntPtr)14/*HTTOPRIGHT*/ ;
                }

                else if (clientPoint.Y <= (Size.Height - 10))
                {
                    if (clientPoint.X <= 10)
                        m.Result = (IntPtr)10/*HTLEFT*/ ;
                    else if (clientPoint.X < (Size.Width - 10))
                        m.Result = (IntPtr)2/*HTCAPTION*/ ;
                    else
                        m.Result = (IntPtr)11/*HTRIGHT*/ ;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (clientPoint.X <= 10)
                        m.Result = (IntPtr)16/*HTBOTTOMLEFT*/ ;
                    else if (clientPoint.X < (Size.Width - 10))
                        m.Result = (IntPtr)15/*HTBOTTOM*/ ;
                    else
                        m.Result = (IntPtr)17/*HTBOTTOMRIGHT*/ ;
                }
                return;
            }
            else if (m.Msg == 0x0083)/*NCCALCSIZE*/
            {
                return;
            }

            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }

        public struct MARGINS
        {
            public int Left;
            public int Right;
            public int Top;
            public int Bottom;
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool GetCursorPos(ref Point point);

        [DllImport("dwmapi.dll")]
        public static extern int DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(IntPtr hWnd, ref MARGINS pMarInset);
```

And this is the custom max-restore button:

```
public class MaxButton : Button
{
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == 0x0084)
        {

            Point screenPoint = new Point();
            GetCursorPos(ref screenPoint);
            m.Result = (IntPtr)9;
         
            return;
        }
        else if (m.Msg == 0x00a1)
        {
            Form form = FindForm();
            if (form.WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized)
            {
                form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            }
            else
            {
                form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            }
            return;
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool GetCursorPos(ref Point point);

   
}
```

I have tried put the DwmExtendFrameIntoClientAreaMethod in other parts for example when handling the NCPAINT message, but results are the same

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30421288/how-do-i-snap-a-borderless-form-to-the-edges-of-a-screen