# Windows Forms fullscreen on drag to top of screen?

Tags: c#, windows, fullscreen

Ive made a custom window with a close and fullscreen button which work fine. The window is also dragable.

But how can I achieve that if i drag the window to the top of the screen that it gets fullscreen and vice versa.

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Boolean fullScreenCheck = false;
    public Point mouseLocation;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private const int SnapDist = 100;
    private bool DoSnap(int pos, int edge)
    {
        int delta = pos - edge;
        return delta > 0 && delta <= SnapDist;
    }

    protected override void OnResizeEnd(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnResizeEnd(e);
        Screen scn = Screen.FromPoint(this.Location);
        if (DoSnap(this.Left, scn.WorkingArea.Left)) this.Left = scn.WorkingArea.Left;
        if (DoSnap(this.Top, scn.WorkingArea.Top)) this.Top = scn.WorkingArea.Top;
        if (DoSnap(scn.WorkingArea.Right, this.Right)) this.Left = scn.WorkingArea.Right - this.Width;
        if (DoSnap(scn.WorkingArea.Bottom, this.Bottom)) this.Top = scn.WorkingArea.Bottom - this.Height;
    }

private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        mouseLocation = new Point(-e.X, -e.Y);
    }

    private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            Point mousePose = Control.MousePosition;
            mousePose.Offset(mouseLocation.X, mouseLocation.Y);
            Location = mousePose;
        }
    }

    private void button1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(fullScreenCheck == false) { 
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            fullScreenCheck = true;
        }
        else
        {
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            fullScreenCheck = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to add this but still doednt work...:(

Answer (score 0):

On windows ten, just creating a default windows form will automatically get fullscreen when you drag window to the top of the screen.
on which Windows version do you want this to achieve ?

Comment: 10. But it doesnt work. I think its because I made a custom window. 
Is there still a way to implement it?

Comment: can you post your code ? did you check this answer ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589268/how-to-make-my-windows-form-app-snap-to-screen-edges

Comment: @xavave this should have been a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @CodingYoshi i didn't know; thank you , i will take this in account next time

Answer (score 0):

I think u need to try this

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
      InitializeComponent();
    }
    private const int SnapDist = 100;
    private bool DoSnap(int pos, int edge) {
      int delta = pos - edge;
      return delta > 0 && delta <= SnapDist;
    }
    protected override void  OnResizeEnd(EventArgs e) {
      base.OnResizeEnd(e);
      Screen scn = Screen.FromPoint(this.Location);
      if (DoSnap(this.Left, scn.WorkingArea.Left)) this.Left= scn.WorkingArea.Left;
      if (DoSnap(this.Top, scn.WorkingArea.Top)) this.Top = scn.WorkingArea.Top;
      if (DoSnap(scn.WorkingArea.Right, this.Right)) this.Left = scn.WorkingArea.Right - this.Width;
      if (DoSnap(scn.WorkingArea.Bottom, this.Bottom)) this.Top = scn.WorkingArea.Bottom - this.Height;
    }
  }
```